# android EditText calculating wrong result

Tags: java, android

I was trying to make a simple APP that converts between Celsius and Fahrenheit:

I wrote two `EditText`, one is for input and another is for output, also I have two buttons (`toC` and `toF`).

The code is as following:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private EditText EditText_input;
private EditText EditText_output;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    EditText_input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input);
    EditText_output = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.output);

    Button toC = (Button) findViewById(R.id.c);
    toC.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String inputS = EditText_input.getText().toString();
            double inputD = Double.parseDouble(inputS);
            double outputD = (5/9) * (inputD-32);
            String outputS = String.valueOf(outputD);

            //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,String.valueOf(outputD),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            EditText_output.setText(outputS, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
        }
    });

    Button toF = (Button) findViewById(R.id.f);
    toF.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String inputS = EditText_input.getText().toString();
            double inputD = Double.parseDouble(inputS);
            double outputD = (9/5) * inputD + 32;
            String outputS = String.valueOf(outputD);

            EditText_output.setText(outputS, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
        }
    });

}
```

After clicking the button `toC`, it always produces 0.0, and clicking the button `toF` would produce a wrong result. I set the `inputType` for the `EditText` as `numerdecimal`, I tried number but still doesn't work.

I checked that the problem is from `outputD`, but I have no idea why `outputD` can't get a correct result.

Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 4):

When you calculate `double outputD = (5/9) * (inputD-32);` the compiler assumes that `5` and `9` are `int`s, so `5/9` is zero. If you want the compiler to treat the numbers as `doubles`, you should write `double outputD = (5.0/9.0) * (inputD-32);`. The same applies to the second conversion - `double outputD = (9/5) * inputD + 32;`

Answer (score 0):

5 and 9 both are integer that is why it always give integer
so 5/9 will always give 0.
Make it
5/9.0
or 5.0/9.0 
it will definately work

Answer (score 0):

Compiler treats division (5/9) as a Integer division. 
Hence first result is always zero.
You can make one of the number as double like 5.0 or 9.0

```
double outputD = (5.0/9) * (inputD-32);
```

Or

```
double outputD = (5/9.0) * (inputD-32);
```

Or

```
double outputD = (5.0/9.0) * (inputD-32);
```